# Обращение к нескольким ip в одной транзакции

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите решить такую задачу:
Необходимо настроить коннект так, чтобы выполнялась транзакция, в которой идёт обращение
к нескольким БД, которые расположенны на двух ip адресах.
Что имеется: 2 ip, их порты, 2 username, 2 pass. Курил этот мануал, но там ни слова о том куда вписывать username\pass.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: через GUI то не проще добавить linked ?

Comment: гуёв нет, это будет использоваться в коде сервака.

Comment: вы связанный сервер планируете добавлять в коде процедуры и удалять потом что ли? смысл в этом есть? почему его постоянно не оставить?

Comment: операция, которая требует данное соединение выполняться будет пару раз в год. Данные все личные, бд огромная, ради безопасности я думаю сразу после выполнения транзакции всё чистить. Плюс, скорее всего, всё это будет разворачиваться на докере. Так что, гуёв нет. Я то только за попроще, но вот так.

Comment: Ну тогда цепляйся за удалённый сервер прямо в запросе. Скажем. через [OPENROWSET()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). И лучше, если максимум работы с удалёнными данными будет выполнен на удалённом сервере, до передачи в локальную обработку (параметр `query`).